# What should be done for a question with a realize-it-was-outside-user-error solution?

Tags: discussion, questions

What I mean is the following situation.

1. Player encounters an error/inconsistency/configuration-issue with a game that has stumped the player.
2. Player makes a question asking how to fix this problem with this game, under the assumption that this is a common error/inconsistency/configuration-issue for that game.
3. Player realizes a few weeks later that the error/inconsistency/configuration-issue had nothing to do with the game but was the result of incomplete hardware installation, forgetting to hit the "Power" switch, or other minor and outside source.

So at this point, the question seems rather invalidated. The question as originally proposed was game-related. But as the solution is irrelevant to the game and more importantly is probably isolated to the player, it doesn't serve a strong purpose to the community.

Are we fine with these being deleted post-revelation? I think it's a good idea, but I wanted to ask around to see if people are fine with this. Otherwise, if there's another solution you think is fine for this scenario, I'd like to hear it as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have there been any examples of this on the site yet?

Comment: @Mana Yes. [ ](http://.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those questions should be deleted (if I remember correctly, I actually deleted such a question).

The thing is, they have zero relation to gaming, and (probably) zero use for anyone else in the future. That means it's complete noise, that should really not be here.

I would make an exception for problems that seem common, and then even if they're not gaming related they can be of use to future gamers on the site. Can't think of any example, though.

Comment: 3864 is the one you deleted, a deletion I agree with and was what inspired me to ask this question. For those who can't see deleted questions, it asked about how to fix sound in a specific game, only to learn that the speakers were plugged into the wrong slot. I agree with both your take on why they don't belong, and your note about valid exceptions. I'll leave this open in case there's any more traffic before I make an acceptance decision.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways for a question to go from here:

1. Answer the question yourself, if it is something that is possible to encounter for other players.
2. Delete the question, if it is really the players fault and not something other players will encounter.

Comment: I agree, answer it yourself or simply delete it.